# What is the & operating doing in this situation

Tags: vb.net

In the function below, what is the meaning of the `&` character? I'm not aware how it's valid syntax or how this would be used normally.

Normally using `&=` together would do a concatenation and assignment, resulting in "Hello world". However in this "typo" the code actually compiles but the result is just an assignment of " world" to the MyStr variable.  Also if you define MyStr in the function rather than at the class level, the result is that it will not compile and interprets the & as a [Type Character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters) and fails because MyStr is a string and not of type Long.

```
Public Class MyClassName

    Private MyStr As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function MyFunction() As String

        MyStr = "Hello"

        MyStr& = " World"

        Return MyStr

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Amusingly, this is a compile time error in VB 2008 ("Type character '&' does not match declared data type 'String'"), but compiles fine in VB 2017. Either there was a peculiar change in the language in the meantime, or it's a bug in Roslyn.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to accept any type character (!,@,#,$,%,&) but they don't seem to actually have any effect, and it just treats it as an assignment. If you try to type MyStr^ = " World" it autocorrects as MyStr ^= " World" and crashes on execution as "Hello" and " World" can't be converted to a Double for running the power assignment operator. Also, I'm testing my code in VS.Net 2019

Comment: That's to be expected because `^` is not a type character. I willing to speculate that Roslyn now has this behaviour, where it ignores the type character based on the [*"The type character is not part of the name of the element"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters), in all places except the variable definition.

Comment: Interestingly, this appears to be specific to field declarations on the class.  It properly fails to compile when used with a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft admits it's a bug in the compiler.

It is [not going to be fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44724#issuecomment-682055795) because that would be a breaking change.

Answer (score -1):

As you mention, the `&` is acting as a type character. Type characters are essentially just a shorthand for declaring the type of a variable. For example, you could use

`dim value& = 100` rather than `dim value as Long = 100`

They are generally used when defining a value on the fly, such as when passing a value to a function:

`dim result = funcThatTakesALong(100&)`

You can also see in the link that you posted there are also type characters for integers (`%`), decimals (`@`), singles (`!`), doubles (`#`), and strings (`$`).

Edit: formatting

Comment: Yep. I'm aware of type characters, but don't really see how they would be used in this context. If it is accepting the & as a type character, then it would be creating a variable of type Long, but then it assigns a string into this supposed long. Also, it doesn't create a new variable in this case, as you can inspect the values in the debugger and see that setting me.MyStr or MyStr or MyStr$ all change the value of the class level variable and all three always have the same value.

Comment: Yeah. This seems like something you would expect the compiler to catch and not allow. It seems like different type characters are ignored on declared members, but treated as conversions on local variables. I would imagine the discrepancy is not intended, so I agree with GSerg that it is probably a compiler bug.

Comment: It looks like in VBA, [using a type character on a variable of the wrong type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/type-declaration-character-does-not-match-declared-data-type) should explicitly throw an error. However, there doesn't appear to be any documentation on the expected behavior of VB.NET in this situation.

Answer (score -2):

```
I think this may explain the purpose of the operators

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    XYZ(9&) '  Long values
    XYZ(9L)

    XYZ(9I) ' Int32 values
    XYZ(9%)

    XYZ(9S) 'Int16 value

    XYZ("9"c) ' a single charcter
    XYZ("9") '  a string
End Sub

Sub XYZ(ByVal arg As Object)
    Debug.Print("arg type is " & arg.GetType.ToString)

    'do some stuff depends on the type of arg

End Sub
```

.

Comment: I know how the concatenation operator works. I'm wondering why the other syntax is allowed and what the purpose of it is. I discovered it as a typo when trying to do concatenation. However, it seems like something that could cause a lot of unexpected bugs as it doesn't seem like anybody knows what this syntax does or even that it exists

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.